# Problem configuring CKEDITOR in Magnolia RichTextField

Tags: ckeditor, magnolia

I can't customize toolbar buttons in Magnolia's RichTextField

- in Yaml file add `configJsFile: /ckeditor/configJsFile.js` pointing to config file under resource folder in java module project

```
- name: text
  class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.RichTextFieldDefinition
  configJsFile: /ckeditor/configJsFile.js
  i18n: true
```

- once configJsFile.js added RichTextField start showing up all imaginable buttons and it is too many

[image: overwhelming toolbar]

I tried to remove some buttons groups in configJsFile.js even comment out all content inside config funtion `CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {  ... }` that's make any effect.

Any idea how I can configure toolbar content in Magnolia's RichTextField?

Here is [original configJsFile.js](https://academy.magnolia-cms.com/download/attachments/152843845/configJsFile.js?version=2&modificationDate=1542859852000&api=v2) taken from Magnolia doc site

Comment: what is your Magnolia version?

Comment: <magnoliaBundleVersion>5.7.4</magnoliaBundleVersion>

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Magnolia are you using?

Worst case scenario you can change the default settings from
'ckeditor/config-default.js'

Hope that helps,

Cheers,

Comment: Unfortunately customer not happy with default toolbar content and want more functions(buttons in toolbar),  Magnolia version 5.7.4

Comment: that said functions suppose to come from CKEDITOR or custom ones?

Comment: If I understand your question right. Buttons are rendered by CKEDITOR according to settings in configJsFile.js. Currently, I realize that Magnolia just doesn't see such file. I tried "configJsFile: /ckeditor/configJsFile.js" and "configJsFile: /.resources/ckeditor/configJsFile.js". Make sure resource folder listed in pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong assuming that magnolia pointed to java resources.

Once I put CKEditor config file into folder from magnolia properties I've got what I wanted

see `magnolia.resources.dir=${magnolia.home}/modules`